# How do you ensure that a data set from a reusable function is available in a template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a reusable file called: `useLanguage.js`

```
import { defineComponent, ref, computed, onMounted, getCurrentInstance} from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default function useLanguage() {

  const store = useStore();

  const data = ref(null);
  
  const profileLanguages = computed(() => {
    return store.getters.allProfiles.data;
  });

  const currentDataSet = computed(() => {
    return store.getters.currentProductSpecification.name
  });

  function availableLanguages() {
    const obj = {}
    const arr = [];
    let i;
    const object = profileLanguages.value;
    const data = JSON.parse(currentDataSet.value)
    
    for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
      arr.push(object[i].language)
      obj[object[i].language] = '';
    
    }

    let y;
    for (const key in data) {
      arr.push(key)
      obj[key] = data[key];
    }
    data.value = obj; 
    console.log(data.value) // Its filled as: {eng: 'english'}
  }

  function updateData(data) {
    currentDataSet.value.name = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
  
  return {
    data,
    availableLanguages,
    updateData
  }
}
```

In my template file called: Filter.vue I call the file useLanguage again and use several functions:

```
<template>
 <div class="modal fade" id="es_modal_edit_text" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="false">
 <div v-for="(value, name) in data" :key="name" class="fv-row mb-7">
   <label class="fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">{{ t("authorized.languageLabels." + name) }}</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" v-model="data[name]" @input="updateData(data)">
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, computed, onMounted, onBeforeMount } from "vue";
import useLanguage from '@/composables/useLanguage';

export default defineComponent({
  props: ['currentId'],
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n();
    const { availableLanguages, data, updateData } = useLanguage();
  
    function update() {
       this.currentProductSpecification.name = JSON.stringify(this.data);
    }
    
    availableLanguages()

    return {
     data,
     t,
     updateData
    }

   }
});
</script>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that within this template I'm trying to create a input field. But `data` is null still. I think it has to do with the fact that data is not available while the template is being created because the function is not ready ( `availableLanguages()` )

How to solve this?

Comment: Please describe better what are you doing. It is quite unusual your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have enough code to go off of here, but a naive solution to your problem would be having a `dataLoaded` flag in your component that gets switched to `true` once the function finishes. You can then use this `dataLoaded` flag in a `v-if` to display a loading indicator, and once it's loaded it'll automatically display the requested data.

Something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="!dataLoaded">
    <p>Loading Data...</p>
  </div>

  <div v-else>
    <!-- Your old code goes here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";

  const dataLoaded = ref(false);
  const data = ref({});

  onMounted() {
    // Return the value that data should be, then set the loaded flag to true
    data.value = availableLanguages();
    dataLoaded.value = true;
  }
</script>
```

This way, Vue will watch the reactive `dataLoaded` value and wait until it turns true. Once it does, it'll automatically replace the div in the template to the proper one, and all the data required will be there.

Comment: Check my total code. I just updated the post.

Comment: @nhatimme Seeing the full code, I indeed think having a `v-if` will fix your issues. It currently breaks because as you say, it doesn't populate the data fast enough so Vue responds by throwing an error at you because the `v-for` encounters a `nil` value. If you add the `v-if` conditional however, Vue won't even attempt to load the `v-for` unless the flag is true, which saves you from the thrown error.